# iOS NSDateFormatter returns old date from string

Tags: ios, nsdateformatter

`NSDateFormatter` `dateFromString` fetched older date.

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
NSDate *date = [dateformatter dateFromString:@"2015-05-18"];
```

The above function returns date as 2015-05-17 11:39:18 +0000 instead of
2015-05-18

Comment: NSDate *date = [dateformatter dateFromString:@"2015-05-17 11:39:18 +0000"]; ?

Comment: [formatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0]];

Comment: I want to get the current date using system/default/local timezone only. I don't want to restrict user statically with GMT or UCT timezone.

Answer (score 1):

Actually you are printing NSDate, if you are printing Date then compiler automatically convert your `date` to `string` by converting using current timezone. if you want actual converted `date` in `NSString` form then add one more line that convert NSDate to NSString like as bellowed.

```
NSDateFormatter * dFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
    NSDate *date = [dFormatter dateFromString:@"2015-05-18"];
    NSLog(@"String : %@",[dFormatter stringFromDate:date]);
```

Output :

```
2015-05-18
```

Comment: Here you are printing Date in log so while logging output. it would expect NSString so compiler automatically convert your date to NSString. that why you saw older date.

Comment: The method that does that is `[NSDate description]` if you want to be a bit more precise about what is doing it.

Comment: @Dhvani Puar, let me know if you are not getting it.

Comment: I don't want the output in string, but in date. If you print date from your code, it will give you a day older date.

Comment: @DhvaniPuar, actually I want said that to see the correct date just take mouse pointer on the date variable at same time whatever compiler show that is correct date. You are printing that date so that's why is displayed older date

Comment: @DhvaniPuar, whatever date you received that is correct. Just you see in wrong way

Answer (score -1):

this is working code to show the current date...might be solve your problem..you should go for this...

```
NSDate *Date = [NSDate date];
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];

NSString *dateFormated = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:Date];
NSLog(@"%@", dateFormated);
```